# Entity Framework-Saving models with related tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So my question basically has to do with nested models or associated tables (not sure the correct term).
Specifically when TableA has an ICollection of TableB objects and TableB has an ICollection of TableA, how do I then save off my entire TableA model along with it's assocaited Table2 items.

For example:

- User table with: string name, string address, ICollection < Orders >
- Orders table with: OrderID, Total, ShipDate, ICollection < User >

So I have a User instance (UserA) which has the name and address set along with a collection of orders (Let's say Bob Dole, 1234 Main st, [567, $12.34, Oct 1; 999, $27.89, Nov 5;]).
How do I trigger the save method to save both Orders & the User?
My expectation would be "db.User.add(UserA); + db.SaveChanges();". I would expect this to save the User and upon seeing the Orders collection, save those as well.

However, previous developers did this:

```
 User userB = db.User.Add(new User(userA.Name, userB.address));     //Why do we have to create a 2nd instance of a User object, that will hold the same information as userA?
 foreach(Order order in userA.orders)
 {
    Order NewOrder = db.Orders.Add(order);  //This now updates the Orders table with new info, which will be saved by 'db.SaveChanges()'
    NewOrder.User.Add(userB);               //How does this update the value in the Orders table with the userID? Isn't this updating the object about to go out of scope?
}
db.SaveChanges()
```

The only thing we can think, is the way they did it userB get's 'ID' assigned from the .Add command. But couldn't you simply say "userA = db.Users.Add(userA)" in order to update the instance with the ID provided upon database insert?

Comment: Is there a model for UserOrder? You are describing a many-to-many relationship. I haven't doublechecked, but I think all that is necessary to save the whole thing is to create a new user and add new orders to the user, as long as you have that middle table and all the foreign keys set up correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think, you've got to change your schema.

There will be one-to-many relationship between `User` and `Orders`. One user can have multiple orders but one order can not belong to multiple users. i.e. Only `Order` table would have `UserId`.

**Update**

Further, No need to add `Orders` data separately. As there would available collection type in the `User` table's entity.

You need to just assign values to the User table's entity along with `Orders` field and do insert it only once.

The code would be somehow as below:

```
var userData = user;
var orderData = orderCollection;
```

`userData` will be single record and `orderData` could be multiple.

Now assign that data to `User` data model:

```
var userAndOrder = new User
{
    Name = user.Name,
    Address = user.Address,
    Orders = orderCollection.Select(o => new Order
    {
        //assign order fields here
    }).ToList();
};
```

Then save this data. It will save `Orders` data itself in the Order table against the UserId.

```
db.Add(userAndOrder);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Imran (funny I have a friend named Imran). Actual tables being used do allow a many to many. I converted over to User & Orders to demonstrate layout while hiding the original table names. In our case 'Table2' can belong to many 'Table1' entries.

Also, the method that actually does the work is passed a User Model. Based on your example I could simply do db.Add(thePassedInModel)) followed by db.SaveChanges() and it will save both models, correct?

ex.
```
public boolean insertRecord (User myUser)
{
     if(myUser != null)
     {    
db.add(myUser); 
db.SaveChanges();
     }
}
```

Comment: amazing coincidence that having a friend with my name. Well, I couldn't get your example. Anyway as you described about the tables, they could also be ADD data in the way as I explained. But you have to fill model correctly.